# How do I change gauge size with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a "found" gauge, and I want to change its size because right now it's not looking nice.

I tried to change it from CSS but my attempts have completely destroyed the gauge.

My code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var gaugeObj = $('#gauge1'),
        gaugeMin = gaugeObj.data('min'),
        gaugeMax = gaugeObj.data('max'),
        gaugeValue = gaugeObj.data('value');
    setRangeText(gaugeObj);
    setGauge(gaugeObj, gaugeMin, gaugeMax, gaugeValue);

    function setRangeText(gaugeObj) {
        gaugeObj.find('.gauge-min').text(gaugeMin);
        gaugeObj.find('.gauge-max').text(gaugeMax);
        gaugeObj.find('.gauge-value').text(gaugeValue);
    }

    function setGauge(gaugeObj, gaugeMin, gaugeMax, gaugeValue) {
        var percentage = (gaugeValue / gaugeMax),
            degrees = 180 * percentage,
            pointerDegrees = degrees - 90,
            spinner = gaugeObj.find('.gauge-spinner'),
            pointer = gaugeObj.find('.pointer');

        spinner.css('transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');
        pointer.css('transform', 'rotate(' + pointerDegrees + 'deg)');
    }

});
```

```css
.gauge-wrapper {
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 4rem;
}

    .gauge-wrapper:not(:last-of-type) {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

.gauge {
    width: 250px;
    height: 125px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.gauge-outer {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 125px;

}

.gauge-inner {
    width: 250px;
    height: 125px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #ddd;
    border-radius: 250px 250px 0 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

    .gauge-inner::after {
        content: '';
        width: 170px;
        height: 85px;
        top: 40px;
        left: 40px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 250px 250px 0 0;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 3;
    }

.gauge-spinner {
    width: 250px;
    height: 125px;
    background: #4bd440;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    transform-origin: top center;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transition: transform 800ms cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.03, 0.06, 1.01);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    border-radius: 0 0 250px 250px;
}

.gauge-range {
    position: relative;
}

.gauge-min, .gauge-max {
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: .5em;
    padding-bottom: .5em;
    width: 40px;
    color: #aaa;
    text-align: center;
}

.gauge-min {
    left: 0;
}

.gauge-max {
    right: 0;
}

.gauge-value {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: .5em;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #000;
}

.pointer {
    display: block;
    width: 6px;
    height: 130px;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 122px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: center bottom;
    transition: transform 800ms cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.03, 0.06, 1.01);
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="gauge-wrapper">
                    <div class="gauge-outer" id="gauge1" data-min="1" data-max="150" data-value="77">
                        <div class="gauge">
                            <div class="gauge-inner"></div>
                            <div class="gauge-spinner alt"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pointer"></div>
                        <div class="gauge-range">
                            <div class="gauge-min"></div>
                            <div class="gauge-max"></div>
                            <div class="gauge-value"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

So I try to change this parameters in css:

```
.gauge {
width: 250px;
height: 125px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

After a few hours of struggle I could not find a solution on how to change the size of this gauge. So now I want make it smaller.
How do I do it without destroying the gauge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updated the css for following classes.

1. .pointer
2. .gauge
3. .gauge-outer
4. .gauge-inner
5. .gauge-inner::after
6. .gauge-spinner

> I just shown way to edit which classed to modify the height, width, border and other css. You have to edit it for your custom size.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var gaugeObj = $('#gauge1'),
        gaugeMin = gaugeObj.data('min'),
        gaugeMax = gaugeObj.data('max'),
        gaugeValue = gaugeObj.data('value');
    setRangeText(gaugeObj);
    setGauge(gaugeObj, gaugeMin, gaugeMax, gaugeValue);

    function setRangeText(gaugeObj) {
        gaugeObj.find('.gauge-min').text(gaugeMin);
        gaugeObj.find('.gauge-max').text(gaugeMax);
        gaugeObj.find('.gauge-value').text(gaugeValue);
    }

    function setGauge(gaugeObj, gaugeMin, gaugeMax, gaugeValue) {
        var percentage = (gaugeValue / gaugeMax),
            degrees = 180 * percentage,
            pointerDegrees = degrees - 90,
            spinner = gaugeObj.find('.gauge-spinner'),
            pointer = gaugeObj.find('.pointer');

        spinner.css('transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');
        pointer.css('transform', 'rotate(' + pointerDegrees + 'deg)');
    }

});
```

```css
.gauge-wrapper {
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 4rem;
}

    .gauge-wrapper:not(:last-of-type) {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

.gauge {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.gauge-outer {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;

}

.gauge-inner {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #ddd;
    border-radius: 200px 200px 0 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

    .gauge-inner::after {
        content: '';
        width: 116px;
        height: 60px;
        top: 40px;
        left: 40px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 200px 200px 0 0;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 3;
    }

.gauge-spinner {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #4bd440;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    transform-origin: top center;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transition: transform 800ms cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.03, 0.06, 1.01);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    border-radius: 0 0 200px 200px;
}

.gauge-range {
    position: relative;
}

.gauge-min, .gauge-max {
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: .5em;
    padding-bottom: .5em;
    width: 40px;
    color: #aaa;
    text-align: center;
}

.gauge-min {
    left: 0;
}

.gauge-max {
    right: 0;
}

.gauge-value {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: .5em;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #000;
}

.pointer {
    display: block;
    width: 6px;
    height: 102px;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 100px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: center bottom;
    transition: transform 800ms cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.03, 0.06, 1.01);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="gauge-wrapper">
                    <div class="gauge-outer" id="gauge1" data-min="1" data-max="150" data-value="77">
                        <div class="gauge">
                            <div class="gauge-inner"></div>
                            <div class="gauge-spinner alt"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pointer"></div>
                        <div class="gauge-range">
                            <div class="gauge-min"></div>
                            <div class="gauge-max"></div>
                            <div class="gauge-value"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a bit unclear. Smaller ? how much smaller ? you can manually change the `height` and `width` keeping in mind the proportions. But you can also use `transform:scale(0.x)` to make it smaller.

For eg I added `.gauge-outer {transform:scale(0.5)}` which will make everything `1/2` of original size.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var gaugeObj = $('#gauge1'),
        gaugeMin = gaugeObj.data('min'),
        gaugeMax = gaugeObj.data('max'),
        gaugeValue = gaugeObj.data('value');
    setRangeText(gaugeObj);
    setGauge(gaugeObj, gaugeMin, gaugeMax, gaugeValue);

    function setRangeText(gaugeObj) {
        gaugeObj.find('.gauge-min').text(gaugeMin);
        gaugeObj.find('.gauge-max').text(gaugeMax);
        gaugeObj.find('.gauge-value').text(gaugeValue);
    }

    function setGauge(gaugeObj, gaugeMin, gaugeMax, gaugeValue) {
        var percentage = (gaugeValue / gaugeMax),
            degrees = 180 * percentage,
            pointerDegrees = degrees - 90,
            spinner = gaugeObj.find('.gauge-spinner'),
            pointer = gaugeObj.find('.pointer');

        spinner.css('transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');
        pointer.css('transform', 'rotate(' + pointerDegrees + 'deg)');
    }

});
```

```css
.gauge-wrapper {
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 4rem;
}

    .gauge-wrapper:not(:last-of-type) {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

.gauge {
    width: 250px;
    height: 125px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.gauge-outer {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 125px;

}

.gauge-inner {
    width: 250px;
    height: 125px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #ddd;
    border-radius: 250px 250px 0 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

    .gauge-inner::after {
        content: '';
        width: 170px;
        height: 85px;
        top: 40px;
        left: 40px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 250px 250px 0 0;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 3;
    }

.gauge-spinner {
    width: 250px;
    height: 125px;
    background: #4bd440;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    transform-origin: top center;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transition: transform 800ms cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.03, 0.06, 1.01);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    border-radius: 0 0 250px 250px;
}

.gauge-range {
    position: relative;
}

.gauge-min, .gauge-max {
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: .5em;
    padding-bottom: .5em;
    width: 40px;
    color: #aaa;
    text-align: center;
}

.gauge-min {
    left: 0;
}

.gauge-max {
    right: 0;
}

.gauge-value {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: .5em;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #000;
}

.pointer {
    display: block;
    width: 6px;
    height: 130px;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 122px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: center bottom;
    transition: transform 800ms cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.03, 0.06, 1.01);
}

.gauge-outer {
transform:scale(0.5)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="gauge-wrapper">
                    <div class="gauge-outer" id="gauge1" data-min="1" data-max="150" data-value="77">
                        <div class="gauge">
                            <div class="gauge-inner"></div>
                            <div class="gauge-spinner alt"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pointer"></div>
                        <div class="gauge-range">
                            <div class="gauge-min"></div>
                            <div class="gauge-max"></div>
                            <div class="gauge-value"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```